# routing to javascript asset in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a small web service app that uses Symfony. It uses the symfony routing system, but when I link a javascript resource it returns a 404 with "route not found" error.

How do you link assets like js, images etc. without creating an individual route for each asset?

Comment: Please provide code samples, currently the question isn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assets` twig function. See more info here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets

Comment: Please add code samples from provided link, as pages can be unaccesible because of downtime, or isp restrictions.